# How to split mysql commands by ; excluding splitting when ; is between apex?

Tags: c#, mysql, regex, split

In a rich text box i have differents string such as :

```
                              show tables;
                              show database;
                              show status;
```

So if i want to do execute all command I'll create one array string doing

```
                       string [] commands = richtextbox.Text.Split(';');
```

now in commands I'll have :

```
                         commands[0] = "show tables";
                         commands[1] = "show databases";
                         commands[2] = "show status";
```

And it works fine! The problem is the following:

```
                              show database;
                              insert into table_x values ("string;s","id_s",1);
                              insert into table2_x values ("s;s",1);
```

Now if I'll do the split I'll break the second and third command. 
I'm thinking about regular expression but how can apply to the split function?
How can I fix that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have more than one command in one line or all that commands are in separate lines ?

Comment: FYI, added explanation for the regex used in the C# demo. :)

Comment: Just to clarify, is the leading whitespace relevant?

Comment: space and \n\r are not relevant

Comment: yes I can have more of one command in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `split` use `Regex.Matches(input, pattern)` with this pattern to skip the content between quotes:

```
@"(?>[^""';]+|""(?>[^""]+|"""")*""|'(?>[^']+|'')*')+"
```

A working example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?>[^""';]+|""(?>[^""]+|"""")*""|'(?>[^']+|'')*')+";
        string input = @"show tables;
                         insert into table_x values (""string;s"",""id_s"",1);
                         insert into table2_x values (""s;s"",1);
                         insert into table2_x values ('s'';s',1);";

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) {
            list.Add(m.Value.Trim());
        }
        string[] commands = list.ToArray();

        foreach (string s in commands) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so how can I do from code? I have to build an array of string with each field has one command. Can i do string []x = Regex.Matches(input, pattern); ??

Comment: You must loop to the matchCollection, you can take a look at the doc for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern should do the trick :

```
string input = "show database;" +
               "insert into table_x values (\"string;s\",\"id_s\",1);" +
               "insert into table2_x values (\"s;s\",1);";
string[] commands = Regex.Split(input, "(?<=^([^\"\r\n]|\"([^\"\\\\\r\n]|\\\\.)*\")*);", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

As debuggex will explain it better than i could do :

```
(?<=^([^"\r\n]|"([^"\\\r\n]|\\.)*")*);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this short regex:

```
"[^"]*"|((?=;))
```

**The beauty of this regex is that it is easy to understand and to maintain if the need later arises.**

This situation sounds very similar to ["regex-match a pattern unless..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174). The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `"quoted strings"`. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures positions preceding semicolos `;` to Group 1, and we know they are the right positions because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

This program shows how to use the regex (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/NFP4Id)):

**Output**

```
*** HERE ARE THE SPLIT STRINGS ***
show database; 
insert into table_x values ("string;s","id_s",1);
insert into table2_x values ("s;s",1);
```

**Sample Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program
{
static void Main()  {
string s1 = @"
show database;
insert into table_x values (""string;s"",""id_s"",1);
insert into table2_x values (""s;s"",1);";
var myRegex = new Regex(@"""[^""]*""|((?=;))");
string replaced = myRegex.Replace(s1, delegate(Match m) {
    if (m.Groups[1].Value == "") return m.Value;
    else return "SplitHere";
    });
string[] splits = Regex.Split(replaced,"SplitHere");
foreach (string split in splits) Console.WriteLine(split);
Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

**Reference**

[How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)